# Prove that there is an integer $N$ such that $\frac{N}{10^k} \leq x \lt \frac{N+1}{10^k}$

Tags: real-analysis

I am having difficulty with this problem. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

x is an element of the real numbers. k is an element of the natural numbers.

Problem: Prove that there is an integer $N$ such that: $$\frac{N}{10^k} \leq x \lt \frac{N+1}{10^k}$$

Thank you.

I've just been staring at the problem for 10 minutes and nothing is coming to me. x is supposed to be some number that falls between the two values I set.

Am I supposed to use something with lower upper bounds or greatest lower bounds? Am I supposed to use this fact?

For any integer k ≥ 1, a k-digit number is an integer n ≥ 0 such that
10^(k−1) ≤ n < 10^k
.

Comment: What have you tried already? Knowing this will help people spend time helping you with the parts you are having trouble with and not waste effort on stuff you already know.

Comment: What are x and k? Are they real numbers, integers? Variables, constants?

Comment: Can we please have the $\forall k,x \in \mathbb{N} \mathbb{R} \mathbb{Z}$ thing

Comment: In future please accept other peoples edits instead of taking them and redoing it yourself, else you add +1 to someones rejected edit count permanently

Comment: You need to be clear that $k$ is an number that is given to you, not one you are allowed to choose.  It is also true if you get to choose $k$, but I suspect that going forward you will need to use the fact that $k$ is given to you.

Comment: Lily, it would help us help you, if you gave more context. For example, you could comment on whether the guesses about the context in my answers are anywhere near the truth. It is very difficult to give a helpful answer, when we don't know the context. For example if the real number system is already at your disposal, then Ross Millikan's answer is the way to go. Otherwise it depends...

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  The naive thought would be to take $N=\lfloor x\cdot 10^k \rfloor$ so multiply your inequalities by $10^k$.  Can you believe it? Can you justify it?

Comment: Ah. So the inequality would be N ≤ x · 10^k < N+1。 Is there a theorem we can apply to x · 10^k? I want to say there is, but my notes from class are not very good.

Comment: You need to look at the definition of the floor function.  You are trying to justify that every real is between two integers (inclusive on the low side).

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that this is an exercise from a course, where the real numbers are constructed, and this is a step towards proving that they have a decimal expansion.

Consider the set of integers $n$ such that $n\le 10^k x$. It is bounded from above (guessing that it has been proven that to each real number there is an integer larger than it). It is non-empty. You may have a suitable earlier result explaining that a non-empty set of integers that is bounded from above has a (unique) largest element (shortly after Peano axioms were introduced).